# Most common reasons ember templates fail to render in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I know this is a broad question but I've failed to find a specific answer and now I feel like I just need to pull the shotgun approach.

I'm trying to load an ember app inside of a rails app. I have ember_controller.rb:

```
class EmberController < FrontendController
  layout 'ember'
  def load
  end
end
```

My Rails routes look like this:

```
MdmFrontEnd::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]

  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  match '*path' => 'ember#load'
  root to: 'ember#load' #makes the root of the app, the ember root.
end
```

My rails layout looks like this:

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %meta{charset:"utf-8"}
    %title= t("layouts.mobile_manager")
    %meta{name:"viewport", content:"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" }
    %link{rel: "icon", type:"image/png", href:"/assets/favicon_16x16.png"}
    = javascript_include_tag "i18n"
    :javascript
      window.locale = "<%= I18n.locale %>";
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' 
    = csrf_meta_tags 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    -if Rails.env.production? 
      :javascript
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-33246783-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
          var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
          ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    = render 'shared/js_constants'
    = javascript_include_tag 'app_ember'
  %body
```

I'm initializing a new ember app in app_ember.coffee with the following:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require handlebars
#= require ember
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./app/routes
#= require_tree ./app/controllers
#= require_tree ./app/models
#= require_tree ./app/templates
#= require_tree ./app/views

window.Mdm = Ember.Application.createWithMixins
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true

  ajax: ->
  $.ajax.apply(this, arguments)

  getUrl: (path) ->
    "/#{path}"
```

Then I have my templates, application.hbs and index.hbs, with an {{outlet}} inside of application.

But when I try and render the root, I just get a blank screen.

I know it's seeing the templates though because in the console when I run Ember.TEMPLATES it lists out each of the template objects.

I feel like its a problem b/t rails and ember but I don't know.

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit:: My Console

[image]

As you can see, it is loading my template objects, but then it also says that it could not find application or index template. My templates directory is named and and located like the other directories - models, controllers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot going on here, hard to say for sure. Some things to consider

1. If your ember app has started properly you should see some console.log output. That would include DEBUG info from ember re: what versions have loaded. If you don't see that, something is wrong with your environment.
2. Since you have set `LOG_TRANSITION: true`, you should see console.log messages like: `Transitioned into 'post.index'` as the router transitions to the current route. If you don't see any of those messages in console when page loads, the app is not booting correctly.
3. Often when I have this kind of issue it's because my naming conventions don't match what ember is expecting. As a result, my code is ignored and ember is working with generated defaults. To see what's going on under the hood, set two more properties when creating your application:

-

```
LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true
```

With this in place, you should see console.log output whenever ember generates a Route/Controller or renders a view. With all this in place, your console.log should look something like this:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4 
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.8.3
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
generated -> route:post.index Object {fullName: "route:post.index"}
Rendering application with <App.ApplicationView:ember785> Object {fullName: "view:application"} 
Rendering post with <App.PostView:ember789> Object {fullName: "view:post"} 
generated -> controller:post.index Object {fullName: "controller:post.index"} 
Rendering post.index with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember796> Object {fullName: "view:post.index"}
Transitioned into 'post.index'
```

Here you can see what classes are being generated, which templates are rendering and what view classes are being used.

Comment: #1 and #2 are good, I did that and the console is rendering the output as it should. Thanks so much for the other two properties, i wasn't aware of them and they may have gotten me a step closer. As you can see from my edit and the screenshot i posted, ember sees the templates when I output Ember.TEMPLATES but then below that it says it cant find application or index template so it is rendering nothing. Any ideas why that might be? Thanks again Mike, I really appreciate it.

Comment: OK I see the problem. Ember is not finding any of your templates because they are all prefixed with "app/". See the line: `Could not find "application" template or view`? That means ember is looking for `Ember.TEMPLATES['application']` and it returns undefined. Not sure what you are using to compile/load the handlebars templates but it is adding "app/" to the front of all your template names, you'll need to change some configuration to remove that prefix. Could be as easy as moving the templates - are they all inside an "app" subfolder?

Comment: Ahh I see. The file structure is rails_app -> app -> assets -> javascripts -> app -> templates -> application.hbs & index.hbs

Comment: Thanks for your time. I very much appreciate it! Just out of curiosity, do you think there is a better way to organize an ember rails app?

Comment: Sure, happy to help. Re: best way to organize, I'm not sure there is one true "right" way. What you're doing is pretty close to how our app is organized. In most cases I suggest starting by using ember-rails gem. It's generators use naming conventions that seem to make good sense. That gives a good starting point then you can customize/change as needed.